# Pandas: How do find the 2 largest sums in each sub group?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a columns A, B, and C. I want to group it on A then sub group on B while taking the sum of C. After that I want to return the 2 highest sums for each group of A.

So an example would look like this.

```
data = {'State': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA'],
        'City': ['New York', 'Buffalo', 'New York', 'Albany', 'SF', 'LA', 'SF', 'SD'],
        'Value': [25, 30, 35, 40, 10, 15, 20, 10],}
```

**Result:**

| State | City | Sum of Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NY | NY | 60 |
| NY | Albany | 40 |
| CA | SF | 30 |
| CA | LA | 10 |

I tried doing

```
summed = df.groupby(['A','B'])['C'].sum() 
grouped = summed.groupby('A').nlargest(2)
```

This gives the correct result but it has a A as a double index from the double groupby(). Is there a cleaner way to get this result without having to have this double index?

Comment: Note sure you are getting results. The dictionary does not have a group by attribute. Can you post the exact code you are using that produces results?

Answer (score 1):

Drop a level of the multi-index and then reset the indices:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'State': ['NY', 'NY','NY', 'NY', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'CA'],
        'City': ['New York', 'Buffalo', 'New York', 'Albany', 'SF', 'LA', 'SF', 'SD'],
         'Value': [25, 30, 35, 40, 10, 15, 20, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

summed = df.groupby(['State','City'])['Value'].sum()
grouped = summed.groupby('State').nlargest(2)

new_index = grouped.index.droplevel()

result = pd.DataFrame(grouped).set_index(new_index).reset_index()
result

# yields
  State      City  Value
0    CA        SF     30
1    CA        LA     15
2    NY  New York     60
3    NY    Albany     40
```